# Why the OSPF router do not have neighbor?

Tags: cisco, router, ospf

I have two Routers in the Cisco Packet Tracer:

[image]

Router2-1, Router2-2, Router2-3 all have their own loopback 0 with IP address `1.1.1.1`, `2.2.2.2`, `3.3.3.3`.

I only launched the OSPF progress in the Router2-1's `Gig0/0/0` port and annunciated .

There is  in the `running-config`:

```
......
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 area 0
!
......
```

there is no neighbor in the `Router2-1`:

```
Router#show ip ospf neighbor 

Router#
```

In logically speaking, there should have a neighbor of Router2-2, why there is none.

---

**EDIT-01**

But, however, after I launched the OSPF 1 in the Router2-2's `Gig0/0/0`, the Router2-1 still can not find the OSPF neighbor.

```
Router#show ip ospf neighbor 

Router#
```

and, in the Router2-2's `running-configuration`:

```
...
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 area 0
!
...
```

how can I know which interface launched the `ospf 1`?

the Router2-1 ospf database:

```
Router#show ip ospf database 
            OSPF Router with ID (1.1.1.1) (Process ID 1)

                Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1         34          0x80000001 0x00510c 0
```

the Router2-2 ospf database:

```
Router#show ip ospf database 
            OSPF Router with ID (2.2.2.2) (Process ID 1)

                Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         325         0x80000001 0x000550 0
```

but each other show the ospf neighbor all get empty result.

```
Router#show ip ospf neighbor 

Router#
```

---

**EDIT-02**

In my Router2-2, the interface:

```
Router>show ip interface brief 
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol 
GigabitEthernet0/0/0   192.168.1.1     YES manual up                    up 
GigabitEthernet0/0/1   192.168.2.1     YES manual up                    up 
Loopback0              2.2.2.2         YES manual up                    up 
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
```

Comment: In order to start an ospf neighbourship, you need 2 devices configured with ospf, to begin that relationship they need to say Hello to each other.

Comment: Do you have IP configured on router interfaces (Gi0/0/0 and Gi0/0/1)?

Comment: see my updated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have IP addresses configured correctly on router's interfaces, you should be good to go. But! Change your **network** configuration in OSPF section to this:

```
router ospf 1
 network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0
```

OSPF network statement uses **wildcard**, not netmask.

**[EDIT]**

As mentioned by **Ron Maupin**, real devices are able to detect user intention and build neighbor relation even with `network 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 area 0`.

Proof:

[image]

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex full
!
router ospf 1
 network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0


R1#sh ip ospf neighbor

Neighbor ID     Pri   State           Dead Time   Address         Interface
2.2.2.2           1   FULL/DR         00:00:26    10.1.1.2        FastEthernet0/0


R1#sh ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C        1.1.1.1 is directly connected, Loopback0
      2.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O        2.2.2.2 [110/2] via 10.1.1.2, 00:14:28, FastEthernet0/0
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        10.1.1.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
L        10.1.1.1/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

**PacketTracer** unable to recognize the situation :

[image]

```
R2#sh ip ospf neighbor 

R2#
```

Comment: The current Cisco IOS is actually smart enough to figure out that `network 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 area 0` is actually `network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0`. It can correct most masks to wildcard masks. We discovered this by accident when an engineer put it in backwards and it worked, then Cisco confirmed that it can fix most things.

Comment: Although, Packet Tracer may not be that smart.

Comment: @RonMaupin Checked in eve-ng 7200VXR and in PacketTracer: PT didn't recognized `0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` and didn't built neighbor connection; 7200VXR - all good.

Comment: I really wish Cisco would just dump Packet Tracer. We get so many questions that are due to the limitations in PT.

Comment: @RonMaupin agree with you. Edited my answer to include your useful quote with some testing.

Answer (score 2):

OSPF is a routing protocol, ie. it is used by routers *participating in OSPF* to exchange their routes and link states. If there's only one router configured to use OSPF in a network there are no neighbors.

Comment: hi, friend. can you tell me where I got wrong? see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0